# Is Buffer Pool Extension (BPE) needed if my database is already on SSD?

Tags: sql-server-2016, performance-tuning

Here is my simplified scenario, let's say I have one (and only one) database of 500GB on SQL Server 2016 EE, this database is on SSD drives already (both data and log files), and my server has 64GB memory, I am thinking to add another SSD drive (let's assume this SSD is of same performance as other SSD drives in the server), and use this new SSD drive for BPE (buffer pool extension) feature, the question is: since my database is already on SSD, does it make sense (or do I get any gain) if I enable BPE in this scenario?

Thanks,
Jeff_yao

Comment: What problem are you attempting to solve by using BPE, and what advantage(s) do you expect to gain vs. adding RAM to the server?

Comment: @alroc, I thought it is obvious in the question itself, i.e. I am not able to add more RAM (for whatever reason)

Comment: You didn't state that you can't add more RAM to the server. Is that a physical limitation of the hardware?

Comment: Not sure why it is down-voted, it is actually very mind-provoking to think about this question, esp. about BP mechanism, and I'd like to even go one step further to ask "if I have BPE on this SSD with the same performance as other drives for databases, does it hurt the performance, if so why? or is the performance the same?" I will put my own "answer" later, but I think the best is to do a test, which is a little bit hard to construct such a test case.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable BPE and test it using your existing SSD drive(s) first to see if you get any performance improvement at all from BPE.  It's going to depend on your workload and waits and if your current SSDs are locally attached as the BPE drive should be.